# How to make sense of Fourier series for a distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, distribution-theory

In particular if I have an array of numbers say, $\{c_m\}_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n}$. Under what conditions can we say that these are the Fourier coefficients of a distribution?

[For examples Bessel's inequality ($\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^n}|c_m|^2<\infty$) tells us these that these are the Fourier coefficients of an $L^2$ function.]

Comment: By a distribution I mean an element in $C^r(S^1)^*$. Shouldn't this space be smaller that $L^2(S^1)$ and hence the dual bigger?

Comment: Then, yes, I believe you're right. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: A motivation for this question is the Bochner-Khinchin Theorem which says if a sequence is positive definite then they are the Fourier coefficients of a finite measure on the circle. So "Bessel's inequality" in this case is replaced by "positive-definiteness"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the Fourier coefficients are of polynomial growth in the index $n$, then they are the Fourier coefficients of a distribution.

In one variable, we know in various ways that for $|c_n|\le |n|^{-2}$ (or even weaker conditions) that the resulting Fourier series gives a $C^o$ function. Thus, differentiating termwise (which is legitimate, distributionally) produces distributions... with coefficients growing polynomially.

Conversely, every sequence of polynomial-growth coefficients is obtained in such fashion.

(An easy on-line reference is the "Functions on circles" notes on my Functional Analysis course page, referring to 2012-13 notes, at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/ )